# Cannot find reference 'connect' in 'function'

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm following Tech With Tim's tutorial on PyQt5
[Video Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-2uyzAqefyE&list=PLzMcBGfZo4-lB8MZfHPLTEHO9zJDDLpYj&index=2)

I'm using PyCharm for this. Here's My Current Code

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
import sys


class MyWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()

        self.setGeometry(200, 200, 500, 500)
        self.setWindowTitle("Data")
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.label1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.label1.setText("Hello World")
        self.label1.move(225, 250)

        self.button1 =QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.button1.setText("Click Me")
        self.button1.move(200, 200)
        self.button1.clicked.connect(self.pressed())

    def pressed(self):
        self.label1.setText("You Clicked")


def window():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MyWindow()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


window()
```

I get a problem that says "Cannot find reference 'connect' in 'function' "
Of course I first tried searching google but they revolve around PyQt4 which I assumed won't answer my problem.

Comment: Please provide the full error message including the traceback.

Comment: change `self.button1.clicked.connect(self.pressed())` to `self.button1.clicked.connect(self.pressed)`

Comment: Your code gives me a different error: `self.button1.clicked.connect(self.pressed()): TypeError: argument 1 has unexpected type 'NoneType'`. This can be resolved by using `.connect(self.pressed)` (without parentheses), and then it runs fine on my machine.

Comment: 1) You must make the change that they have indicated, 2) the warning that you indicate only evidence of a bug in your IDE (most likely pycharm) is not capable of recognizing methods created in C++, I recommend you ignore that warning